# Adwords API: Using campaigns and ads from live on the sandbox

Tags: php, testing, google-ads-api

I'm using the Adwords API so that a client can auto-pause the ads associated to some of their communities based on certain criteria. My problem lies with how I can reliably test that this is set up correctly without having to modify their live Adwords campaigns. **I know about the sandbox**, but a blank slate is not really helpful to test against.

**Is there a way to transfer over some of the adgroups/campaigns over from their account, or do I have to rebuild everything manually in the sandbox?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no automatic way to achieve this, but you could use the API to pull the structure of the production account and then create an analogous structure in the sandbox.

Comment: I guess if you helped develop the library I'm talking about, you can be trusted as a pretty authoritative source. Just out of curiosity, was this a conscious decision to not be able to import into the sandbox, or more just not enough time for the project?

Comment: Well, the idea of sandbox is to keep the development environment separate from the production account so that those writing code won't make any assumptions that will break their code in subtle ways later - we've seen people's code break because they hard coded on login email, campaign ids and what not. It might be convenient for the developers at the point of development, and since it works, no one bother fixing it until things break pretty bad later. So yes, it was a conscious decision. And yes, Eric and I are part of that team.